# GitHub sphinx-action can't find target Python modules and builds an empty sphinx doc

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, github-actions, autodoc

#### Tl;dr

When I create a sphinx doc locally it builds as expected, but the [GitHub Sphinx Build Action](https://github.com/ammaraskar/sphinx-action) creates an empty doc. It must have to do with the sphinx-action not finding the target python modules as specified in `conf.py`.

Any ideas to configure the sphinx-action or `conf.py` correctly?

#### Expected Sphinx Doc

When I build the sphinx doc locally on my machine via `cd docs/ && make html` the resulting html looks as expected

[image: expected_sphinx_doc]

#### Empty Sphinx Doc generated by sphinx-action

My `.github/workflows/sphinx_action.yml` includes

```
    steps:
    # Checkout repo
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    # Build sphinx doc
    - uses: ammaraskar/sphinx-action@master
      with:
        docs-folder: "docs/"
```

and generates an empty skeleton of a Sphinx Doc

[image: output_shpinx_doc]

#### Project Setup

Project Structure

```
.
├── docs
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── index.rst
│   ├── make.bat
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── sync.log
├── .github
│   └── workflows
│       └── sphinx_action.yml
├── .gitignore
├── mypackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── subfolder
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── subclass.py
│   └── superclass.py
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
└── README.md
```

**`conf.py` Configuration**

My `docs/conf.py` looks as follows. (Mind that I added three entries to the `sys.path` manually in order to make Sphinx find all python modules.)

```py
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# This file only contains a selection of the most common options. For a full
# list see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html


# -- Path setup --------------------------------------------------------------

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#
import os
import sys
from m2r import MdInclude

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../mypackage'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../mypackage/subfolder'))


# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'MyPackage'
copyright = ''
author = 'Testuser'


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc',
              'recommonmark'
]

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

#
source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This pattern also affects html_static_path and html_extra_path.
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']

# document the init of a class, too
autoclass_content = 'both'

# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
html_theme = 'nature'

# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']

# from m2r to make `mdinclude` work
def setup(app):
    config = {
        # 'url_resolver': lambda url: github_doc_root + url,
        'auto_toc_tree_section': 'Contents',
        'enable_eval_rst': True,
    }

    # from m2r to make `mdinclude` work
    app.add_config_value('no_underscore_emphasis', False, 'env')
    app.add_config_value('m2r_parse_relative_links', False, 'env')
    app.add_config_value('m2r_anonymous_references', False, 'env')
    app.add_config_value('m2r_disable_inline_math', False, 'env')
    app.add_directive('mdinclude', MdInclude)
```

**Pipfile**

```
[[source]]
verify_ssl = true
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
name = "pypi"

[dev-packages]

[packages]
m2r = {index = "pypi",version = "==0.2.1"}
pandas = {index = "pypi",version = "==1.0.3"}
sphinx = {index = "pypi",version = "==3.1.0"}
recommonmark = {index = "pypi",version = "==0.6.0"}
mypackage = "*"

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

*Note:* I posted this question also as an [issue in the GitHub repo of the sphinx-action](https://github.com/ammaraskar/sphinx-action/issues/17).

Comment: From the README: "If you have any Python dependencies that your project needs (themes, build tools, etc) then place them in a requirements.txt file inside your docs folder." Your project is a dependency and it must be installed.

Comment: Mh you are right. But how can I add `mypackage` itself to the requirements? Doesn't `pip` assume that every package mentioned is to be downloaded from the same index (= `PyPi`)? I managed to install `mypackage` via adding `pre-build-command: "pip install -e .`, yet the sphinx builds an empty doc. I realized that locally sphinx only builds successfully within the pipenv shell. But adding `pre-build-command: "apt install pipenv && pipenv install -e . && pipenv shell"` didn't help either.

Comment: Try `-e .`. That's what Read the Docs does.

Comment: Unfortunately `-e .` didn't work @StevePiercy. I surrendered and try to automate the sphinx doc building without GitHubActions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. Simply putting

```
import mypackage
```

in `conf.py` fixed things for me.

**Edit:** `mypackage` above refers to the actual package name and will be specific. In order for this to work, you need to make sure that the package is actually installed (e.g. using `setuptools`). Below are code snippets for GitHub actions

```
    - uses: ammaraskar/sphinx-action@master
      with:
        #pre-build-command: "apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y pandoc"
        docs-folder: "docs/"
```

and my `requirements.txt` file (in `docs`)

```
sphinx>=3.3
sphinx-autodoc-typehints
sphinx-argparse
-e .
```

I left the commented-out `pre-build-command` as you can use it to `pip install -e .` also. I don't think the sphinx version matters.

Comment: I tried ur solution, but the GithubAction failed - because Github couldn't find `mypackage`: `Configuration error: There is a programmable error in your configuration file: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/config.py", line 348, in eval_config_file
    execfile_(filename, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sphinx/util/pycompat.py", line 81, in execfile_
    exec(code, _globals)
  File "/github/workspace/docs/conf.py", line 16, in <module>
    import mypackage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage'`.

Comment: `mypackage` just refers to the package name (not sure what you use) but that’s likely not the issue  ... Sphinx needs to find the package: in my case, I use setuptools to get it installed. Putting `-e .` in the requirements.txt file (see Sphinx-action instructions) should make it available (same as running `pip install -e .` in the preconfiguration step).

Answer (score 0):

Build your path inserts deterministically. For example, using `__file__`:

```py
_HERE = os.path.dirname(__file__)
_ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(_HERE, '..'))
_PACKAGE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(_HERE, '../mypackage'))
_SUBPACKAGE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(_HERE, '../mypackage/subfolder'))

sys.path.insert(0, _ROOT_DIR)
sys.path.insert(0, _PACKAGE_DIR)
sys.path.insert(0, _SUBPACKAGE_DIR)

# test the path; not strictly needed
import mypackage
```

This way, the resolved locations are always the same, regardless of the present working directory.